# how to disable Touch Screen in Android Phone?

Tags: android, android-activity, listactivity

while showing progress bar i want to disable touch screen to restrict other functionalities in android phone.

can any one guide me how to achieve this?

any help would be appricated.

Comment: This would be taking control away from the user and a bad idea so I doubt it can be done and I dont see why anyone would want it to be done

Comment: ok, when i show progress on list, i have implemented on click functionality on list item.during progress bar is activited if some one press list item. it takes control to some other activity so i want to restrict that.

Comment: Just remove the onClick functionality from the list?

Comment: i cant its necessary. any other suggestion?

Comment: If you've tried my solution and it worked, could you mark it as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT

You can do it by implementing a custom extension of ListView which you set as the list to use in your XML file. Then in your CustomListView, implement the onTouchEvent method and only call super.onTouchEvent if you want the touch to be processed by the list. Here's what I mean:

Have something to this effect in the layout file that contains your list.

```
<com.steve.CustomListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/start_menu_background"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:id="@android:id/list">
</com.steve.CustomListView>
```

Then have a custom class like this:

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView {
    Context mContext;

    public CustomListView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        if (event.getRawY() < 100){
            Log.d("Your tag", "Allowing the touch to go to the list.");
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.d("Your tag", "Not allowing the touch to go to the list.");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This code will only allow touch events to get processed by the ListView if they're in the top 100 pixels of the screen. Obviously, replace that if statement with something more appropriate for your application. Also don't leave in the Log statements once you've got it to work since you'll spam yourself with hundreds of logging lines after each gesture; they're only their to make obvious what is happening.